# How many days would it take to go from Hogwarts to London by carriage?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

I am making a fanfiction story about Harry Potter set  in the 19th century. The main character lives in London, attends Hogwarts, and returns home during Christmas and whenever they let them go home.

**How far is Hogwarts from London, and how many days would it take to return home?**

Comment: If you travel by thestral-drawn carriage, zero days

Comment: @Valorum Thestral all the way from Scotland? Your carriage is either driven by a monster, or by an invisible force, and it might even be flying - Muggles are out with torches and forks way before you've left Scotland

Comment: @Jenayah - hence why you use a [Disillusionment Charm](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Disillusionment_Charm)

Comment: @Valorum if it's fanfic, I vouch for Thestral-carriage-sized Invisibility Cloak. Waaaay cooler.

Comment: For large-scale transport, I'd vote for connecting the nation's destructors to the floo network.

Comment: I felt my answer was pretty comprehensive. Is there anything else you'd want to see before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 11):

The *exact* location of Hogwarts isn't specifically known, but we do know that [it's in Scotland](http://members.madasafish.com/%7Ecj_whitehound/Fanfic/map_of_Hogwarts/location.htm). If we take *the most likely* location, (near Argyll and Bute) that places it some 500(ish) miles from your destination in London.

[image]

Assuming your carriage is drawn by mundane horses, replenished en-route and you don't mind getting up early, [you'll make about 30ish miles in a day](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-average-speed-of-a-horse-drawn-carriage) or a **total journey time of about 15(ish) days.**

---

Since that means an effective round-trip of a month (*excluding* any time spent at home), I'm at a loss why you wouldn't use one of the many faster alternatives available to wizards.

> Wizards who cannot Apparate (dematerialise and reappear at will), who wish to travel by daylight (meaning that broomsticks, Thestrals, flying cars and dragons are inappropriate), or whose destination has no fireplace (rendering Floo powder useless) will have to resort to the use of a Portkey.
>
> <sub><sup>[Portkeys By J.K. Rowling](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/portkeys)</sup></sub>

If you're desperate to have your character in a carriage for some reason, there are also better options than *horses*.

[image]

And a muggle train on the newly opened Caledonian line (available after 1850) would take you [just 13 hours to get from Scotland to London](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caledonian_main_line) at a much cheaper ticket price than a carriage.

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is an *excellent* answer! :)

Comment: Why is Argyll and Bute the most likely location for Hogwarts?

Comment: @TheDarkLord - Click the clicky-link; http://members.madasafish.com/~cj_whitehound/Fanfic/map_of_Hogwarts/location.htm

Comment: Ah, OK. I knew it was in Scotland already so didn't click the link in your answer. Whitehound's always thorough.